# How to get name wise all subjects mentioned next to the name column, consolidated name and all subjects separated by a comma?

Tags: mysql

I have data like this:

[image]

And I want output like this using SQL or SAS

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MySQL

```
select name,group_concat(subject)
from mytable
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

`select name,group_concat(subjects) from courses group by name;`

check here [on fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f35c6/1)